# Conditional strings in plsql like sprintf

Tags: plsql

Writing the below code gives me error saying:

> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type:

Code:

```
    if ( l_vol = 0 ) 
    then 
        l_cndtn_string := 'l_wgt > l_wgt_limit';            
    else
        l_cndtn_string := '(l_wgt > l_wgt_limit) and (l_vol > l_vol_limit)';
    end if;

    if ( l_cndtn_string )
    then
        l_isis_task := 'PO';
    else
        l_isis_task := 'TO';
    end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

[If statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/if_statement.htm#LNPLS01324) evaluates a [boolean expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/expression.htm#CHDDGEFH). In your example

```
if ( l_cndtn_string )
```

`l_cndtn_string` is not a boolean expression but a [character expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/expression.htm#CHDGJCJE) and there is no implicit cast between them.

Please help yourself and check [Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS00206) too.

I don't know what is your logic but the following example shows you one way to convert character expression into boolean expression:

```
if l_cndtn_string is not null -- a boolean expression
then
  null;
else
  null;
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want dynamic condition build. In `plsql`,like other compiled languages, it hard to do.

Try like this:

```
if ( l_vol = 0 ) 
then 
    if(l_wgt > l_wgt_limit) then
      l_isis_task := 'PO';
    end if;           
else
    if(l_wgt > l_wgt_limit and l_vol > l_vol_limit) then
      l_isis_task := 'TO'; 
    end if;
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

After `IF` boolean expression is expected, not a string - that's why you're getting PLS-00382 error. You can of course try to dynamically evaluate your expression using dynamic sql, but in fact what you want is as simple as:

```
if ( l_wgt > l_wgt_limit and ( l_vol = 0 or l_vol > l_vol_limit ) )
then
    l_isis_task := 'PO';
else
    l_isis_task := 'TO';
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, only after reading the other answers I realised what this question was about. I decided to keep also my original answer as the point about character expression in if-statement is still correct.

The other answers are correct that buiding a logic based on string evaluation with dynamic PL/SQL is not a good idea in general. They also present correct solutions, but IMHO even better approach exists.

Usually when I have multiple conditions in PL/SQL I give the conditions a name. Please see the example below that illustrates the technique. The names make the code self-documenting and is a huge improvement in code readability as very often the condition now reads as human language.

```
declare
  v_volume number := 0;
  v_weight number := 1;

  v_weight_limit constant number := 10;
  v_volume_limit constant number := 10;

  v_has_volume constant boolean := v_volume > 0;
  v_exceed_weight_limit constant boolean := v_weight > v_weight_limit;
  v_exceed_volume_limit constant boolean := v_volume > v_volume_limit;
begin
  -- no guarantee the logic is the same than in question
  -- but just illustrates the coding style
  if  v_has_volume
  and v_exceed_weight_limit
  and v_exceed_volume_limit
  then
    null; -- something
  else
    null; -- something else
  end if;
end;
/
```